# Same chart event, same X-axis, different Y-axis for ng2-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am leveraging the following ChartJS framework for an Angular 2 application:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts

http://www.chartjs.org/

I'm looking to do the following:

1. Stack one bar chart on top and one line chart below that–basically two `<canvas></canvas>` tags on the HTML page.
2. In it, it'd share the same X-axis values (e.g. time) but different Y-axis values (e.g. bar chart would be 1, 2, 3, 4 whereas line chart would be A, B, C, D).
3. Both charts would leverage the same `chartHover` and/or `chartClick` event.

Ideally, I'd like the user to hover over either chart but share the same interaction. For example, if a user were to hover the bar chart, a vertical line would appear on both the bar chart and line chart (and vice versa).